# Tensorflow from tensor slices attribute error

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert pandas dataframe into Tensorflow dataset to build a model upon. But from_tensor_slices gives error. Any idea to fix it or another way to use pandas df in tensorflow model?

Thanks in advance.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()


df = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')
X = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['sex', 'smoker', 'region'])
y = X.pop('charges')

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X.values, y.values))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\tracking.py", line 269, in 
__del__
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4011, in as_default
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_controller'
```

Comment: Try: `from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()`

Comment: @Erfan still the same error.

Comment: Not sure then, check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8652) topic.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it now, and I am posting the answer for those who get the same error.

You need to add the line below before `from_tensor_slices()` line:

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```